# Comment XML section (having prefixes in the nodes) and un-comment other

Tags: xml, powershell

This is my sample xml data. Please ignore if there is any syntax error or some missing xml features.
The task is to comment the above section and un-comment the below section.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<providersbeans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/providers"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:dns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/dns"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/dns/spring-dns.xsd">

<!-- COMMENT THIS SECTION -->

<dns:auth-head alias="authHead">
    <dns:user-generator>    
        <dns:user-data>

            <!-- USER AA -->
            <dns:user name="AA"
                password="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" role="ROLE_AA" />

            <!-- USER BB -->
            <dns:user name="BB"
                password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" role="ROLE_BB" />

        </dns:user-data>            
    </dns:user-generator>
</dns:auth-head>


<!-- UNCOMMENT THIS SECTION-->
<!-- 
<bean id="authHead" class="org.xx.providers"> 
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="AuthProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
-->
</providersbeans>
```

I tried some of the solutions but couldn't get success since it has a prefix in it.
One of the code that I adapted for just commenting is this:

```
$getxmlpath='C:\Powershell\securityfile.xml'
$xml=[xml](Get-Content $getxmlpath)
$xml.SelectNodes("//auth-head") | ForEach-Object # used with prefix as well, but didnt work
{ 
  $var= $_;
  $mycomment = $xml.CreateComment($var.OuterXml);
  $var.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($mycomment , $var);
}
$xml.Save($getxmlpath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Powershell\securityfile.xml'

# create namespace manager
$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('dns', $xml.DocumentElement.dns)

# remove nested comments from <auth-head> node(s)
($xml.SelectNodes('//dns:auth-head//comment()', $nsm)) | % {
  [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}
# comment-out node(s)
($xml.SelectNodes('//dns:auth-head', $nsm)) | % {
  $comment = $xml.CreateComment($_.OuterXml)
  [void]$_.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($comment, $_)
}

# uncomment <bean> node(s)
($xml.SelectNodes('//comment()')) | ? {
  $_.InnerText -like '*<bean*'
} | % {
  $newxml = [xml]$_.InnerText
  $node = $xml.ImportNode($newxml.DocumentElement, $true)
  $node.SetAttribute('xmlns', $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
  [void]$_.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($node, $_)
}
```

I was unable to find a way to re-insert the `<bean>` node without it getting an explict (empty) namespace attribute (`xmlns=""`), so I set that attribute to the default namespace of the XML document.

Note that you *must* remove (or otherwise modify) the nested comments from the node you wish to comment out. Otherwise the closing `-->` from the first nested comment would prematurely terminate the comment node, leaving you with an invalid XML structure:

```xml
<!--dns:auth-head alias="authHead">
    <dns:user-generator>    
        <dns:user-data>

            <!-- USER AA -->   # XML comment ends here!
            <dns:user name="AA"
                password="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" role="ROLE_AA" />

            <!-- USER BB -->
            <dns:user name="BB"
                password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" role="ROLE_BB" />

        </dns:user-data>       # tags from here on are invalid, because
    </dns:user-generator>      # they're missing their respective opening tag
</dns:auth-head-->
```

Comment: Thank you,just need to save the file. Anyway, didn't think that way to first eradicate all comments, since with the comments still there on the xml, it wasn't working at all, at least for me.  Appreciate your prompt help again

Comment: @Kriti The nested comments prematurely terminate the commented-out node, leaving you with invalid XML. I added a note about that to my answer.