# Trying to comment XML nodes using VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I want to comment some nodes (tags including values) as i have to automate configuration using VB script.

I am able to find the node but i have to comment that node when needed via scripts.

I want to avoid reading entire file and finding the required node as there can be sub nodes and it will be really complicated

Can some guide me plz

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31839167/1630171) to a similar question. The code is PowerShell there, but the approach is the same: select the node, put it into a new comment node, and replace the original node with that.

Comment: I have to use vbscript as the code base is in vbscript, i cant change to powershell for 1 single use

Comment: I didn't say you should switch to PowerShell. But you can use the PowerShell code as a blueprint of sorts for implementing this in VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am doing now. plz anyone help me to do it in a better way.
-> I am reading a text from file and replacing it with comment tag appending to the text

```
sub CommentNodes(OriginalFilepath, TempFilePath , OriginalText, UpdatedText)

mOriginalFilePath = OriginalFilepath
mTempFilePath = TempFilePath

Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(mOriginalFilePath)
Set OFile = FileSysObj.CreateTextFile(mTempFilePath , True)
StrText = File.ReadAll
newStr = Replace(Strtext, OriginalText, UpdatedText)
OFile.WriteLine newStr

OFile.Close
File.Close
FileSysObj.DeleteFile mOriginalFilePath
FileSysObj.MoveFile mTempFilePath,mOriginalFilePath 

Set OFile = Nothing
Set File = Nothing
Set FileSysObj = Nothing

Wscript.Echo "Success"
End sub
```